# Allow mail to be sent from any subdomain (PTR, SPF, Gmail)

Tags: email, exim, gmail, reverse-dns, ptr-record

I use a single smarthost as a hub to route all email from my network so that I can pass SPF checks on Gmail.  However, although I always send through the same server, the `From` address can differ.  For instance, a cron job on the server `dev.mydomain.com` might generate the From address `amoe@dev.mydomain.com`.  I use `/etc/aliases` to redirect this cron email to my real email address.  This email uses hosted Gmail, so the MX for `mydomain.com` points to Gmail's servers.

However, Gmail doesn't like these `From` addresses, probably because they don't exactly match the SPF record which is defined on `mydomain.com`.  I receive the message that `Our system has detected that this message does not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding PTR records and authentication`.

I don't want to have to define separate SPF records that allow my one mail server to submit email for every single subdomain that I want to allow in the `From` address.  Instead, I'd like to allow `*@*.mydomain.com`, as long as it is sent through the correct server.

```
2016-12-22 14:04:17 1cK3yj-0007Wz-4I <= amoe@dev.mydomain.com H=(dev.mydomain.com) [2a01:7e00::f03c:91ff:fe79:81b] P=esmtp S=586 id=E1cK3yj-0006Nx-0y@dev.mydomain.com
2016-12-22 14:04:17 1cK3yj-0007Wz-4I ** real@mydomain.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp X=TLS1.2:ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:128 DN="C=US,ST=California,L=Mountain View,O=Google Inc,CN=mx.google.com": SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: host ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com [2a00:1450:400c:c07::1a]: 550-5.7.1 [2a01:7e00::f03c:91ff:febb:7422] Our system has detected that this\n550-5.7.1 message does not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding PTR records\n550-5.7.1 and authentication. Please review\n550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError for more information\n550 5.7.1 . p21si28305523wmb.29 - gsmtp
```

I am using Exim on Debian.

[Edit: It seems the cause was the reverse DNS/PTR record.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the message from Google mentions PTR records, I think that perhaps the problem is not with SPF in this exact case, but instead caused by a missing PTR record for your server. If you check the URL mentioned in the message: https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError under "Additional guidelines for IPv6", you should have a PTR record for your server (and a matching AAAA record pointing back to the same IP address). And if `2a01:7e00::f03c:91ff:febb:7422` is the IPv6 address of your server it does not have a PTR record.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this.  Looks like I can't read!  I will set up reverse DNS and try again.

Comment: There may of course also be some SPF issues, but the current issue looks like a PTR issue. For setting up SPF you need to look at the `Mail From` envelope sender, and not the `From:` Header (depending on the mail-server these may be the same). You can possible use the `include` mechanism to point the sub-domains SPF records to a common record with the actual information.

Comment: That fixed it, now mail is being accepted by Gmail regardless of the `From` address.